# How to modify add to cart form in detail

Tags: 8, commerce

Currently add to cart form can be modified from the "manage form display" of the line item. But this place shows all the attributes as a single entry.

Where is the best place to modify the sorting of attributes, inject other elements to the form between attributes etc?

For example I want to show an image field (from product) just before "add to cart" button. Should I use form_alter or is there a twig file that I can readily use?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this answer may be a little late, but for those that end up here looking for a way to display the product variation fields (price, add to cart buttons, etc) separately, you can do it through the commerce-product.html.twig template using something like this:

```
<article{{ attributes }}>
  {{ product.title }}
  {{ product.body }}
  {{ product.variation_price }}
  {{ product.variations }} //show add to cart button
</article>
```